# Can't show source code by using pygment to highlight code

Tags: pygments

I choose the package `pygmentex` to highlight my source code in LaTeX.  I compile the `test.tex`using the following command:

`xelatex -shell-escape test.tex`

But it doesn't work, there is no code on the PDF.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pygmentex}
\begin{document}
    Hello World
    \begin{pygmented}[lang=c++]
#include<cstdio>
int main(){
    printf("Hello World");
return 0;
}
    \end{pygmented}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pygmentex/demo.pdf), the package generates a `.snippets` file and you must run the external program `pygmentex` on this file. The `-shell-escape` flag is not necessary for the LaTeX runs.

Relevant section of the manual (page 1 at the bottom):

> When compiling the document (with `pdflatex`, for instance), all the
>   source code listings in the document wil be collected and saved in a
>   temporary file with the extension `.snippets` in its name. Then the
>   auxiliary program `pygmentex` (a Python application distributed with
>   the PygmenTEX package) should be run taking this file as input. It
>   will produce another temporary file with the extension `.pygmented`,
>   containing LATEX code for the code listings previously collected. The
>   next time the document is compiled, they are included to produce the
>   final typeset document.

For the example you can therefore use the following compile sequence:

```
xelatex test.tex
pygmentex test.snippets
xelatex test.tex
```

Result:

[image]